# How to get Wikipedia Article length through API?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api, wikidata, wikidata-api

If I have article URL, how can I get the article metadata? specially length, category and son on? I'm developing Java application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check available options for the `query` action at the [help page of the MediaWiki API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query).

For instance, given Albert Eintein's Wikipedia article, you can get the length (in bytes) of the latest revision as follows:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=Albert Einstein&prop=revisions&rvprop=size
```

To get the following result:

```
{
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "query": {
    "pages": {
      "736": {
        "pageid": 736,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Albert Einstein",
        "revisions": [
          {
            "size": 139015
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To get the categories the page belongs to use the following query:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=Albert Einstein&prop=categories
```

You may need to fetch further results with `continue`

Comment: Thanks a lot atineoSE !